# Django user id is null

Tags: django

I have a user in my django table - auth_user. The username = 'django' but when I check the id its None.

[image]

When I check in the tables, the id is set to 1.

Not sure why u.id is None.

Comment: The id gets assigned only when it is saved to the database. In this case, you have only instantiated an object in memory, so there is no id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code creates a user object but does not save it to the database:

```
# here u.id is None
u = User(username="django")
```

An id is associated to a new user object whenever it is added to the database:

```
# here u.id is not None
u = User.objects.create(username="django")
```

If the user object already exists, then it can be loaded from the database and the `id` attribute will be properly defined:

```
u = User.objects.get(username="django")
```